# GetLastError 127

Tags: windows, winapi

Why does the following code always print out 127 ("The specified procedure could not be found.") even though it finds "firefox.exe" and terminates it successfully??

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (_tcscmp(entry.szExeFile, TEXT("firefox.exe")) == 0)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                DWORD d = GetLastError();
                cout<<d<<'\n';
                TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing successful about `TerminateProcess()`. It kills it dead with no effort at clean up. Let's hear it for corrupted profiles!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check return values for specific functions **before** checking `GetLastError`.

`GetLastError` will always return the last error code that was set by by an API function. However, not all functions will set the last-error code when they **succeed**. So the result from `GetLastError` may be an error code that was set at some other part of your program.

So in your case, according to the MSDN docs for `OpenProcess`, the function will return `NULL` if it fails. Hence there's no need to look at `GetLastError` if `OpenProcess` returns other than `NULL`.

Note that the last-error code **is** unique to the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

This is a common pattern in the Windows API, GetLastError is often only valid when the function fails... (Some functions like [GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and GetFileType require you to call GetLastError to tell if the returned value is valid)